# Why are my docker container and local files not in sync?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal, containers

Just trying to get a dev env set up locally using OS X, VSCode and a very trim `docker-compose.yml` file with the `drupal:latest` docker image:

```
version: '2'

services:
  drupal:
    image: drupal:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:  
      - './:/opt/drupal'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.6.14
    environment:
      MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: true
      MARIADB_USER: root
      MARIADB_DATABASE: d10
```

The build is working with `docker-compose up -d`, and I can load and run the install scripts and make it to the admin.

However:

- If I toss in a `die` statement to the `./web/index.php` file, I still see the admin.
- If I restart the container, I see the `die` statement.
- If I modify the `die` statement, I see the original `die` statement.
- If I restart the container, I see the new `die` statement.

Seems like the changes are only being picked up on the full container restart.

I have a similarly bare-bones Symfony docker-compose file using the `bitnami` images, and that container syncs any changes in the files between the host and container.

I feel like it's got to be something pretty basic but am unable to figure out the right combination of settings in the `docker-compose.yml` file - thx for any help!

Update: so it appears that it's not that the container is not in sync with the local, but that the process that syncs the 2 systems is timed: if I change the index.php file with a new `die` statement, and then wait about 90s, refreshing the browser will show the new value - is there a way to decrease this refresh rate..?